# Add a column at a specific location in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe-

```
data={'a':[1,2,3,6],'b':[5,6,7,6],'c':[45,77,88,99]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now I want to add a column at a two rows down in the dataframe.

The updated dataframe should look like-

```
 l=[4,5] #column to add

    a   b   c   d
0   1   5   45  0
1   2   6   77  0
2   3   7   88  4
3   6   6   99  5
```

I did this-

```
df.loc[:2,'f'] = pd.Series(l)
```

Answer (score 2):

Idea is add `Series` by index with length by `list`:

```
df['d'] = pd.Series(l, index=df.index[-len(l):])
print (df)
   a  b   c    d
0  1  5  45  NaN
1  2  6  77  NaN
2  3  7  88  4.0
3  6  6  99  5.0
```

Last for `0` values add [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by original `index`

```
df['d'] = pd.Series(l, index=df.index[-len(l):]).reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
print (df)
   a  b   c  d
0  1  5  45  0
1  2  6  77  0
2  3  7  88  4
3  6  6  99  5
```

Another idea is repeat `0` values by difference of lengths and add `l`:

```
df['d'] = [0] * (len(df) - len(l)) + l
print (df)
   a  b   c  d
0  1  5  45  0
1  2  6  77  0
2  3  7  88  4
3  6  6  99  5
```

Comment: what is the reindex doing?..it seems to work without it also

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - Added both solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can add a col with `0`s and set the index:

```
>>> df
   a  b   c
0  1  5  45
1  2  6  77
2  3  7  88
3  6  6  99
>>> df['d'] = 0
>>> df.iloc[-2:, df.columns.get_loc('d')] = [4,5]
>>> df
   a  b   c  d
0  1  5  45  0
1  2  6  77  0
2  3  7  88  4
3  6  6  99  5
```